# Laravel 5.5. Can't instantiate class with a specific name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I have 2 classes: `\App\Services\WeatherService` and `\App\Services\WeatherService1` both are equal.

In my `\Tests\Unit\Services\WeatherServiceTest` I'm trying to make a new instance, but I can't instantiate `\App\Services\WeatherService`.

```
//Works perfect
$some = new WeatherService1(new \Forecast\Forecast(config('darksky.key')));

dd($some);

/*
App\Services\WeatherService1 {#2405
  -forecastApi: Forecast\Forecast {#2406
    -api_key: "somekey"
  }
}
*/
```

And original weather service gives

```
//Not working
$some = new WeatherService(new \Forecast\Forecast(config('darksky.key')));

dd($some); //app\Services\WeatherService {#2405}
```

What could be done to solve this issue?

Comment: What is in you logfile? It looks like that you do not store the Forecast in a property in the class `WeatherService`. Need to see the class `app\Services\WeatherService` BTW try to us `App\Services\WeatherService`

Comment: @Webdesigner the problem is that I've copy-pasted `WeatherService1` form `WeatherService` and only renamed it. The rest is identical.

Comment: But somthing must be different, maybe you missed something

Comment: @Webdesigner No. I've moved to *Docker* and now it works as it should without any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another test I had such a `use` statement.

```
use app\Services\WeatherService;
```

changing to

```
use App\Services\WeatherService;
```

has solved the problem.

Here is the code of the class. Probably, sb knows why it was so. But it was very strange.

```
class WeatherControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    private $mock;
    private $cities;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->mock = \Mockery::mock(WeatherService::class);
    }


    public function tearDown()
    {
        \Mockery::close();
    }

    //...
}
```